# How do I access a JSON file relative to my calling module in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I'm defining a package, PackageA, that has a function (parseJson) that takes in a file path to a json file to parse. In another package, PackageB, I want to be able to call PackageA using a file I specify with a local path from PackageB. For example, if file.json is in the same directory as packageB, I'd like to be able to call `PackageA.parseJson('./file.json')`, without any extra code in PackageB. How would I do this? It seems that `require` requires a path from PackageA to the file, which is not what I want.

Edit: Currently, parseJson looks something like this:

```
public parseJson(filepath) {
    let j = require(filepath);
    console.log(j);
}
```

and PackageB is calling it like this:

```
let a = new PackageA();
a.parseJson("./file.json");
```

file.json is in the same directory as PackageB.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

CommonJS modules have [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) variable in their scope, containing a path to directory they reside in.

To get absolute path to `RELATIVE_PATH` use `join(__dirname, RELATIVE_PATH)` ([`join` from `path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)).

example:

```js
// PackageB .js file
const Path = require('path')
const PackageA = require(/* PackageA name or path */)
const PackageB_jsonPathRelative = /* relative path to json file */
// __dirname is directory that contains PackageB .js file
const PackageB_jsonPathAbsolute = Path.join(__dirname, PackageB_jsonPathRelative)

PackageA.parseJson(PackageB_jsonPathAbsolute)
```

---

##### UPDATED

If you can't change PackageB, but you know exactly how `PackageA.parseJson` is called by PackageB (e.g. directly, or through wrappers, but with known depth), then you can get path to PackageB from [stack-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace).

example:

```js
// PackageA .js file

// `npm install stack-trace@0.0.10` if you have `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` error
const StackTrace = require('stack-trace')
const Path = require('path')

const callerFilename = (skip=0) => StackTrace.get(callerFilename)[skip + 1].getFileName()

module.exports.parseJson = (caller_jsonPathRelative) => {
  // we want direct caller of `parseJson` so `skip=0`
  // adjust `skip` parameter if caller chain changes
  const callerDir = Path.dirname(callerFilename())
  // absolute path to json file, from relative to caller file
  const jsonPath = Path.join(callerDir, caller_jsonPathRelative)
  console.log(jsonPath)
  console.log(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(jsonPath)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, really appreciate it! How would I achieve this without making any changes to the contents of PackageB? ie, only through changes to PackageA's parseJson method.